# How can I read content in my manifest JSON in my Chrome Extension JavaScript code?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to get the content of the manifest.json in my extension context? For example, in my background.js, I want to get the content of "content_scripts" in the manifest.json file. Something like:

`chrome.manifestJson.content_scripts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [chrome.runtime.getManifest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-getManifest) API:

```
The object returned is a serialization of the full manifest file.
```

To access the content of `content_scripts` in the manifest.json file, you can therefore write:

```
var manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
console.log(manifest.content_scripts);
```